# Laravel - Filter to Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use Filters to check if the user is a guest... if so, use a method in a Controller.... let me know if I'm doing this right...  I keep getting the error `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given`

So routes:

```
Route::get('/', ['before' => 'checkUserFilter'], function()
{
    return View::make('home');
});
```

Filter:

```
Route::filter('checkUserFilter', function() 
{
    if (Auth::guest()) 
    {
        Route::get('/', 'User@createUser');
    }

});
```

Controller

```
public function createUser($username)
{

    $username = 'test-'.str_random(4);
    $newUser = new User;
    if ($username == null) {
        $newUser->username = 'user-'.str_random(4);
    } else  {
        $newUser->username = $username;
    }

    $newUser->password = str_random(8); // ignore this line.....
    $newUser->save();

    Auth::login($newUser); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must redirect, in this case you can use `action()`, and you also need to create a route for that action, out of your filter, so, this could be your code:

```
Route::filter('checkUserFilter', function() 
{
    if (Auth::guest()) 
    {
        return Redirect::action('User@createUser');
    }

});

Route::get('/createUser', 'User@createUser');
```

**EDIT:**

Why you ned to create that `/createUser` route?

Because Redirect will basically look for a route that points that action and redirect to the URI related to the route. So, Redirect will send your browser to http://app.com/createUser.

If you don't create this route Redirect will raise a `NotFoundHttpException`.

Comment: Thanks, I assume /createUser where it has to be called? I'm not sure about that little part? Also am I calling my controller right? Which is UserController.php

Comment: Alright, I understand now. I am getting a Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::callAction() though

Comment: `callAction` is a controller method. If Laravel is trying to call it on a QueryBuilder object, you can have some mixed class names in your code. Is Redirect also a class name of yours?

Comment: No, the only class names are HomeController and UserController